# How to convert an image to html syntax as 0's and 1's, like a mask (example attached)?

Tags: html, css, image-processing

So here's the ss from the website http://rainy.im/ :

[image]

How can I convert an image to this style?
The [source code](https://github.com/rainyear/rainyear.github.io/blob/master/index.html) for the website contains this:

```
<pre><font color="#f6f8fd">1</font><font color="#f7f8fd">0</font><font color="#f8f9fd">10110</font><font color="#f9fafe">111</font><font color="#fafbff">0</font>
```

and so on... I think that there's a generator for this.

Comment: pick a language to do that in. you need to read/decode an image file, then work with its pixels.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the image you can try something like below:

```css
/* we repeat a lot of 0 and 1 */
.box:before {
  --0: "0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 ";
  --1: var(--0) var(--0) var(--0) var(--0);
  --2: var(--1) var(--1) var(--1) var(--1);
  content: var(--2) var(--2) var(--2) var(--2);
}
/**/
.box {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #0000;
  /* we color the text with the image */
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1069/400/400) center/cover;
  -webkit-background-clip: text; 
          background-clip: text;
}

body {
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: @ransom I simply gave you the idea, you have to adjust everything like you want (width, height, image, etc)

Comment: got it, but how can it be converted to html code like in the source code for the website?(https://github.com/rainyear/rainyear.github.io/blob/master/index.html)